# Suitescript 2.0 Display an array within an array with sublists

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I'm creating a custom UI with a Suitelet, and I'm using the serverWidget module. I'm trying to represent an array of data, that can contain sub-arrays within them. I can't really find a great way to do that with the Suitescript APIs, as sublists only allow single fields within them. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
customers = [
  {
    name: '',
    number:
    contacts: [{
     contactType:
     contactName:
    }]
  },
  {
    name: '',
    number:
    contacts: [{
     contactType:
     contactName:
    }]
  },
  {
    name: '',
    number:
    contacts: [{
     contactType:
     contactName:
    }]
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you give a little more detail, or an example of what the data might look like and how it should display?

Comment: So normally, sublists would be just fine for 1D arrays, but now there are multiple elements within my array that are also arrays. So like a list of customers, where each customer has a list of contacts attached to them. Representing another layer of data like that doesn't seem to work with a sublist. I'm thinking I'll have to write custom code to support something like that. I will edit my post to give a better example of data

Answer (score 0):

Render the data in an inline html field,  then you can display or anyway you like.

Comment: yeah, this is my fall-back plan, but I would prefer to stay within the Netsuite APIs just for consistencies sake